# Upload file working when using ip address instead of domaine name

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, filesize

When i try to upload an image in my project using ip adress it's working but when i try to use my serverName instead it's not working. For example, I tried the following:

```
exmple.com/my-project/upload
```

accept only file <50 ko or i get connection aborted
However

```
195.25.66.33:81/my-project/upload
```

works perfectly 
Are there any solutions for this issue? 
here's my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost ***.**.**.**:81>
       ServerName exmple.com
        <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    Deny from all
        </Directory>


    ServerAdmin webmaster@star.com.tn
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mrh"
    ErrorLog "logs/mrh-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mrh.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: but it works when the file is less than 50 ko ? when i type exmple.com:81 it shows me that the Url does not exist

Comment: exmple.com:81 !== 195.25.66.33:81 it depends on configuration. Could you please post your host preferences?

Comment: i added the conf part ? is there somthing wrong with my conf ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the domain via default port 80, or via 81? The configuration you have shown is for access via :81 only.

Comment: Also, call phpinfo() both ways, and check what the limits relevant to file uploads are set to - same in each case, or are there differences?

Comment: sorry there's no diifferent in file limit but here"s defference in the http header information is that a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

On the IP version you specify port 81.
Try:

`exmple.com:81/my-project/upload`

Comment: but it works when the file is less than 50 ko ? when i type exmple.com:81 it shows me that the Url does not exist (connection refused)

Comment: You have given no configuration information.
Does the IP map to the same domain name?

Comment: i added the conf part !!